strapi custom migration for mysql database
i want custom table that why i am using knix for that which is creating the table for me but when i restart the app . strapi own migration is automatically delete my table which is created by knex . and i also tried to stop the strapi internal migration by giving option migration safe . but it not worked for me
i tried by stopping the internal strapi migration to apply the knex migration btw i am using mysql for my database related query . i already created a knexfile where my up down and database attributes is .

That is not possible, you have to create separate database, otherwise your table would be reset on every project startup
